# Is it possible to identify whether the highest value within a row is unique?

Tags: r

I'm trying to compare different shares of apartments (with respect to their size) within a specific area against each other. The data would look like this:

```
df <- data.frame (rbind(c(0.33, 0.33, 0.33), c(0.6, 0.4, 0), c(0,0.4,0.6),c(0.25,0.35,0.6)))

names(d) <- c("30-50", "50-70", "70-90")
```

[image]

All row sums equal 1 (or 100%) and the value in each column represents the share of apartments with a particular size in the area (area 1 for row 1)

I now want to add an additional column that gives out the name of the column for the highest value in each row. Therefore, I am using this code:

`df$highest_value <- names(df)[apply(df, 1, which.max)]`

this gives out the following column vector:

`[1] "30-50" "30-50" "70-90" "70-90"`

for row 2:4 the results are correct as they contain one single highest value. However, for row 1 the results are incorrect as they all have the same share of the total amount of apartments in that area (all 33,333...%) but the highest_value column gives out the name of the first column. Is there a way to identify whether the highest value is unique within the row? If so I would like the vector to display "mix" for these scenarios. The highest_value column would then look like this:

`[1] "mix" "30-50" "70-90" "70-90"`

I hope the provided information is sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame (rbind(c(0.33, 0.33, 0.33), c(0.6, 0.4, 0), c(0,0.4,0.6),c(0.25,0.35,0.6)))

names(df) <- c("30-50", "50-70", "70-90")

df

# check which values are max?
df == apply(df, 1, max)

## count the occurrences of the max values
rs <- rowSums(df == apply(df, 1, max))

# if there is > 1 occurence of a max value, then "mix", otherwise continue with your previous code
df$high <- ifelse(rs > 1, "mix", names(df)[apply(df, 1, which.max)])

df
```

Comment: You can at least vectorize `apply(df, 1, max)` with `do.call(pmax, df)` and save it so you don't have to calculate it twice. Remember, `apply` with margin 1 is very inefficient as it coerces to matrix first

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked perfectly!!!! is there a way I can credit people for helping me other than upvoting (which is not displayed as I do not have a rating yet) ?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sweep` to compare row-wise maximum. If there are more than 1 maximum values in the row we return `"mix"` or else return the column name.

```
inds <- sweep(df, 1, do.call(pmax, df), `==`)
ifelse(rowSums(inds) > 1, "mix", names(df)[max.col(inds)])
#[1] "mix"   "30-50" "70-90" "70-90"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that only loops once per row, avoids several `apply` calls and uses `vapply` which is safer by specifying the output of what you're expecting:

```r
df <- data.frame (rbind(c(0.33, 0.33, 0.33), c(0.6, 0.4, 0), c(0,0.4,0.6),c(0.25,0.35,0.6)))
names(df) <- c("30-50", "50-70", "70-90")

# split each row into a list
list_rows <- asplit(df, 1)

# Loop through each row
vapply(list_rows, function(x) {

  # Count the ocurrence of each number
  count_pos <- table(x)

  # If there's any number repreated twice, return mix, otherwise return the max
  if (any(count_pos > 1)) {
    return("mix")
  } else {
    names(x)[which.max(x)]
  }
}, FUN.VALUE = character(1))
#> [1] "mix"   "30-50" "70-90" "70-90"
```